# How to get multiple html array contents with php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have an issue using jquery to append an create more input tags, so i can collect multiple data and be treated as an array. But each time i process it with php, only one data is sent.Kindly help out.

```
<div class="half" id="bs_cat">
    <form method="POST">
        <div>
            <div class="label">Create Category</div>
            <div class="label" id="bs_cat1"><input type="text" class="form_element" name="bs_category[]" placeholder="Football, handball, basketball e.t.c" /></div><br />
        </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="label half center">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Create Categorie(s)" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a class="button" href="#" onclick="$('#bs_cat').append('<div>'+$('#bs_cat1').html()+'<a href=\'#\' onclick=\'$(this).parent().remove(); return false;\'>>>Remove this item<<</a></div>'); return false;">Add Another Category</a>
</div>
```

Here is the php i have processing it

```
$bs_category = $_POST['bs_category'];
    $n = 0;
    foreach($bs_category as $c){
        if(!empty($c)){
            $bs = $afrisoft->antiHacking($c);
            $sQl = $afrisoft->dbcountchanges("INSERT INTO sport (bs_categories) 
            VALUES ('$bs')");
            if($sQl > 0) $n++;
        }
    }
```

I'll appreciate any help i can get. Thanks

Comment: You mean to say that the user should enter multiple values in your input box and you wish to insert them in SQL?

Comment: @GauravBhor i mean after using jquery to make more input fields after clicking on add new category, and i submit. Only the first input box is captured in php.

Comment: Have you tried console logging the values you send?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the name bs_category on the form itself rather than the input field

Comment: Currently the input tag has an attribute with the name bs_category. Try putting the form tag instead